# (If String in Variable) statement is not filtering out data

Tags: python, ironpython

Trying to filter out data that don't have 'PC' in the string, but it doesn't seem to catch anything and just goes to the else. Not sure if csvRow is even a string, and maybe that's why it's not working, but I just started Python and dunno how to interpret that.

Sample data returned by csvRow:

```
['0', '0', '30', 'Testing Unit', 'True', 'COMP_PC', 'COMP_PC']
['0', '0', '30', 'Prod Unit', 'True', 'ASSM_UL', 'ASSM_UL']
```

Code:

```
for csvRow in reader(csvRows[2:]):

    if "PC" in csvRow: 
        for csvValue in csvRow:
            values += csvValue + "\t"
        values = values[:-1] + "\r\n"
    else:
        continue
```

Edit:

Cobbled a solution for this, though I'm not sure if it's efficient at all.
Any tips?

```
for csvRow in reader(csvRows[2:]):
    for csvValue in csvRow:
        if "PC" in csvValue: 
            for csvValue2 in csvRow:
                values += csvValue2 + "\t"
            values = values[:-1] + "\r\n"
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: you mentioned 'PC in the question and using 'PCM' in the code

Comment: Sorry, that one's a mistake. Should be PC in code.

Comment: `csvRows` came from `file.readlines()` and is lines of text from a file?

Comment: use `print(csvRow)` to see what you get in `csvRow`

Comment: @tdelaney, csvRows comes from a web request and split into an array        
 csvHolder = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
 csvRows = csvHolder.split("\n")

Comment: `"PC" in string` can check if `"PC"` is part of longer string. `"PC" in list` check if there is exactly string "PC" on list - but it can't check if "PC" is part of longer string on this list.`

Comment: That's reasonably efficient for this bit of code. You could do `if not any('PC' in value for value in csvRow)` instead of the inner `for` but that's trivial. I don't understand the whole tab/newline thing though. Typically a csv writer is used for that. And you may gain a bit by skipping the intermediate `cvsRows` list and filter/write for each line as you read it in.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, I gotta \r\n because this code is in Spotfire, which uses TSV better than CSV, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you want to use an alternative delimiter (i.e. `\t` instead of `,`), it's still a good idea to use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). It will do a better job of generating well-formed output.

Here's an example:

```
import csv
import io

# Representing csvRows as a 2D array, hopefully approximating your input.
csvRows = [
    ['0', '0', '30', 'Testing Unit', 'True', 'COMP_PC', 'COMP_PC'],
    ['0', '0', '30', 'Prod Unit', 'True', 'ASSM_UL', 'ASSM_UL'],
]

# Using a StringIO instance to capture the output, alternatively you
# can easily write to a file.
results = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(results, delimiter='\t')

# Process your data.
for row in csvRows:
    if any('PC' in value for value in row):
        writer.writerow(row)

# Print the results.
output = results.getvalue()
print(output)

# Use repr() to verify that each line is terminated with '\r\n'.
print(repr(output))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 example.py
0       0       30      Testing Unit    True    COMP_PC COMP_PC

'0\t0\t30\tTesting Unit\tTrue\tCOMP_PC\tCOMP_PC\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, as furas said:

> `"PC" in string` can check if "PC" is part of longer string. `"PC" in list` checks if there is exact string "PC" in list - but it can't
>   check if "PC" is part of longer string in this list.`

Just had to iterate over the list and check there.

```
for csvRow in reader(csvRows[2:]):
    for csvValue in csvRow:
        if "PC" in csvValue: 
            for csvValue2 in csvRow:
                values += csvValue2 + "\t"
            values = values[:-1] + "\r\n"
            break
        else:
            continue
```